# I want to extract a particular string from the following message.(oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to extract a particular string from the following message.
I have a message that somewhat looks like this

```
"{1:kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk}{2:kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk}{4:
:20:M000000043319452
:25:kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkUR
:28C:00037/00012
:60M:FGHYYGGGG,52
:61:1402210221CR180,ABCDEFGHIJK//25-15974720-2
BE762/051/DFRR. DFGHYUJI
:86:ADDFCVBG Paid In/AVCDFGHUJKI
kkkkkkkkkk:kkkkkkk GMBH BNK:kkkkkkkkkkkkkkk ACT:ABCDEFGHIJK
INFO:ABCDEFGHIJK CUST111006
:61:1402210221CR588,ABCDEFGHIJK//25-15974757-2
BE762/051/UEB. kkkkkkkkkkkkkk
:86:ADDFCVBG Paid In/XW3000-CT2014-02-21-12.15.45.171881
kkkkkkkkkkk:Mayer ABCDEFGHIJK BNK:RVSADEMX ACT:ABCDEFGHIJK
INFO:GGHJUGG ADDEW 95268AAAAADDDD9646 SSSSS
:61:1402210221DR585854,23NTRFNONREF//25-1SSSSSS768-1
M051/206/FVGBHHHHH.
:86:ADDFCVBG Paid Out Manual
BEN:DD DD DD DD DD
INFO:kkkkkkkkkkkk kkkkkkkkkkkkkkk
:61:1402210221CR285,14NTRFCreditor Payment//25-15975438-2
BE762/051/UEB. BBBBB
:86:BBBBB Paid In/ABCDEFGHIJUKL
kkkkkkkkkkk:Hella KGaA Hueck  BNK:kkkkkkkkkkkkkk ACT:ABCDEFGHIJK
INFO:INV 952687857 05.02.2014
:62F:ABCDEFGHIJK,1
:64:ABCDEFGHIJK,05
:65:ABCDEFGHIJK,1
-}{5:{CHK:kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk}}"
```

I want to take out 00012 from the 28c tag. I want to extract whatever that comes after / in the 28c tag and before the 60M tag i,e before :60M:
Please provide me any suggestions as im totally new to oracle.

Answer (score 2):

```
regexp_substr(swift_message, ':28C:.*?/(\S*)', 1, 1, '', 1)
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7ea4d/2)

Comment: Hey thanks a lot fiddle. Cn you please explain me what exactly are you doing .?

Answer (score 0):

IF you have this massage content in a column of a table then u can do it as

```
SELECT SUBSTR( SUBSTR( message, INSTR(message,'28C'), INSTR(message,':60M')-INSTR(message,'28C')),INSTR(SUBSTR( message, INSTR(message,'28C'), INSTR(message,':60M')-INSTR(message,'28C')),'/')+1) AS Output_String
FROM table_name
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/403ff/1)
where message is collumn name i picked and table_name is name of table

Comment: Thanks a lot Vikas for your answer. As you said thet message is in the table